(ngSubmit)="animalSubmit()" - form not actually going into my animalSubmit() function
component html file:
<div class="row g-2 mt-4 ml-2">

  <form [formGroup]="animalForm" (ngSubmit)="animalSubmit()" id="animalForm" class="row g-3">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Enter Animal ID"             formControlName="id" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-3 mt-4 ml-3"> Create New Animal </button>

  </form>

</div>

app-component.ts file
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceService } from '../service.service';
import {
FormGroup,
FormControl,
ReactiveFormsModule,
Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-create',
standalone: true,
imports: \[ReactiveFormsModule\],
templateUrl: './create.component.html',
styleUrl: './create.component.css',
})
export class CreateComponent {
constructor(private api: ServiceService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

}

animalForm = new FormGroup({
id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
created_At: new FormControl(() =\> new Date().toISOString()),
updated_At: new FormControl(() =\> new Date().toISOString()),
});

animalSubmit() {
console.log('hey');
console.log(this.animalForm.value);
}
}

So obviously I'm trying to print out my submitted inputs to the console. However, I get no output to the console. That "console.log('hey')" is there because THAT doesn't even print out. When I submit the form, nothing happens. It doesn't look like ngSubmit is working and calling my animalSubmit() but I have all the imports in my module.ts form. Why isn't the form submitting and calling my function? keep in mind, this "animal" data i'm supposed to send back to in my MySql Database. I'm watching a year old video of this guy doing the basics, because somewhere in my old project my CRUD functions got all messed up, so I restarted basically and am watching how this guy did it. It all works out fine for him. But I have a newer version of angular (18) and things don't work sometimes like how his does.
YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjVpnGz862o%60


Did you try (submit)="..."?

Check this Link
It uses Angular 18 and it is working fine.

@bottletyre and Pieterjan
okay I see when I click on the link both work fine. So why does it not show up on my own localhost webpage? Or my vs code? Worst case scenario I guess I just use stackblitz, but it's weird it's not working regularly without it

As @bottletyre already said in the comment, the code seems to work fine in Angular 18. 
The only things I could think of would be: 
Try removing the backslashes from your ReactiveFormsModules import. Maybe the import is invalid since a backslash usually shouldnt be there. 
Or dont call the function from ngSubmit() but from (click) on your button as a workaround. 

Those slashes aren't there on my code, must've been added when I inserted it here. I also did change it to click, and still nothing. My supervisor says something has to be wrong for nothing to be showing up in my brower console. I'll figure it out, thanks though!
